# I use a Symfony CollectionType form and it generate too many child objects

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony5, easyadmin

hope someone can help me, I trying to make a form to create a custom carousel. So I need to upload several images for it. I am currently using a form with a collection type to handle this. But each time I upload some images it create a carousel per image.

Here is the code and the result:

CarousselType: (i just copy-pasted the useful part)

```
        $builder
            ->add('legend', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Legende"
            ])
            ->add('autor', TextType::class, [
                'label'=> "Auteur"
            ])
            ->add('articleCarousselImgs', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CarousselImgType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => 'Images',
                "by_reference" => false,
            ])
        ;
```

CarousselImgType

```
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
                'label' => "Fichier Image"
            ])
        ;
```

The usefull part of my entities:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ArticleCarousselImg::class, mappedBy="articleCarousel", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $articleCarousselImgs;
```

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ArticleCaroussel::class, inversedBy="articleCarousselImgs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $articleCarousel;
```

It's rendered with easyadmin

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        
        $associationUser = AssociationField::new('author', 'Auteur')
            ->setFormTypeOption(
                    'query_builder', function (UserRepository  $userRepository){
                        return $userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :role OR u.roles LIKE :role2')->setParameter('role', '%ROLE_REDACTEUR%')->setParameter('role2', '%ROLE_REDACCHEF%');
                    }
            );
        return [
            TextField::new('title', "Titre"),
            TextField::new('chapo', "Chapô"),
            BooleanField::new('isPremium', "Article Premium"),
            //BooleanField::new('isNewsLetter', "Envoyer en Newsletter")->onlyOnForms(),
            //BooleanField::new('isSocialMedia', "Partager automatiquement sur les reseaux sociaux")->onlyOnForms(),
            DateField::new('publicationDate')->hideOnForm(),
            $associationUser,
            AssociationField::new('categories', 'Categorie(s)'),
            CollectionField::new('images', 'Image(s)')
                ->setEntryType(ImageType::class)
                ->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)
                ->onlyOnForms()->setColumns(' col-lg-6'),
            TextEditorField::new('content')
                ->setFormType(CKEditorType::class),
            CollectionField::new('articleCaroussels','Carroussel(s)')
                ->setEntryType(CarousselType::class)
                ->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)
                ->onlyOnForms()->setColumns(' col-lg-6'),
            CollectionField::new('images')
                ->setTemplatePath('Admin/images.html.twig')
                ->onlyOnDetail(),
        ];
```

And the result:

```
  -articleCaroussels: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#958 ▼
    -elements: array:2 [▼
      0 => App\Entity\ArticleCaroussel {#2164 ▼
        -id: null
        -legend: "Des photos incroyables de tableaux stats"
        -autor: "Thofile"
        -article: App\Entity\Article {#938}
        -articleCarousselImgs: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#2167 ▼
          -elements: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\Entity\ArticleCarousselImg {#2230 ▼
              -id: null
              -file: null
              -articleCarousel: App\Entity\ArticleCaroussel {#2164}
              -imageFile: null
              -updatedAt: null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
      1 => App\Entity\ArticleCaroussel {#2251 ▼
        -id: null
        -legend: null
        -autor: null
        -article: App\Entity\Article {#938}
        -articleCarousselImgs: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#2252 ▼
          -elements: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\Entity\ArticleCarousselImg {#2318 ▼
              -id: null
              -file: null
              -articleCarousel: App\Entity\ArticleCaroussel {#2251}
              -imageFile: null
              -updatedAt: null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

You see, there is 2 carousel with one image par carousel and i don't understand why...

I'll be glad to find someone who can explain why this happens and how to fix this

Comment: This needs more code. How are your rendering this (twig) and how are the new collection elements added to the page (javascript)? And how are you processing this form in your controller?

Comment: I added to the post how it's rendered, and the processing is also done by easyadmin and i didn't touched it in an event subscriber